# Summing Multiple Groups of Columns

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, purrr, summarization

I have a situation where my data frame contains the results of image analysis where the columns are the proportion of a particular class present in the image, such that an example dataframe `class_df` would look like:

```
id    A    B    C    D    E    F
 1 0.20 0.30 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.00 
 2 0.05 0.10 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.40
 3 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.30
```

Each of these classes belongs to a functional group and I want to create new columns where the proportions of each functional group are calculated from the classes. An example mapping `class_fg`

```
class         fg
    A          Z
    B          Z
    C          Z
    D          Y
    E          Y
    F          X
```

and the desired result would be (line added to show the desired new columns):

```
id    A    B    C    D    E    F |    X    Y    Z
 1 0.20 0.30 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.00 | 0.00 0.40 0.60
 2 0.05 0.10 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.40 | 0.40 0.40 0.20
 3 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.30 | 0.30 0.40 0.30
```

And I can do it one functional group at a time using

```
first_fg <- class_fg %>%
  filter(fg == "Z") %>%
  select(class) %>%
  unlist()

class_df <- class_df %>%
  mutate(Z = rowSums(select(., one_of(first_fg))))
```

Surely there is a better way to do this where I can calculate the row sum for each functional group without having to just repeat this code for each group? Maybe using purrr?

Comment: Yes that's called **aggregation** then summarization. Do `class_fg %>% group_by(fg) %>% summarize(...your summary code goes here...)`

Comment: Sorry @Ronak, updated correctly. "label" should have been "class"

Comment: @smci - I don't see how that would allow me to create a summary for the class_df which is what I'm actually wanting to summarize?

Comment: Your code was confusing because you never named your df. (Is it called `class_fg` or `class_df`? What is `class_df`?) Either way, the solution you want is `whatever_your_df_is_actually_called %>% group_by(fg) %>% summarize(...your summary code goes here...)`

Comment: Sounds like it might be useful to transform `class_df` into long form, then join in the `fg` based on `class`, then aggregate and transform back to wide format. It's hard to say without actually being able to see the data though; could you provide a runnable example?

Comment: I've updated to make the examples clearer. I'm working with a very large data set where I'm unsure if I can share (and using it as an example would be too large here), so hopefully the improved examples help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could `split` the 'class_df' by 'class', loop through the `list` elements with `map`, `select` the columns of 'class_df' and get the `rowSums`

```
library(tidyverse)
class_fg %>%
    split(.$fg) %>% 
    map_df(~ class_df %>%
                select(one_of(.x$class)) %>% 
                rowSums) %>%
    bind_cols(class_df, .)
#  id    A   B    C    D    E   F   X   Y   Z
#1  1 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6
#2  2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2
#3  3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3
```

---

Or do a group by `nest`ing, and then do the `rowSums` by `map`ping over the `list` elements

```
class_fg %>% 
   group_by(fg) %>%
   nest %>%
   mutate(out = map(data, ~  class_df %>%
                               select(one_of(.x$class)) %>% 
                               rowSums)) %>% 
   select(-data)  %>%
   unnest %>% 
   unstack(., out ~ fg) %>% 
   bind_cols(class_df, .)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the feeling that it was possible with a single statement like that. I'm still coming to grips with how to nest effectively without immediately resorting to creating a long format table.

Answer (score 6):

Always it is easier to work on data in long format. Hence, change `class_df` to long format using `tidyr:gather` and join with `class_fg`. Perform analysis in long format on your data. Finally, spread in wide-format to match expected result.

```
library(tidyverse)

class_df %>% gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  inner_join(class_fg, by=c("key" = "class")) %>%
  group_by(id, fg) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(fg, value) %>%
  inner_join(class_df, by="id") %>% as.data.frame()

#   id   X   Y   Z    A   B    C    D    E   F
# 1  1 0.0 0.4 0.6 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0
# 2  2 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4
# 3  3 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3
```

**Data:**

```
class_fg <- read.table(text = 
"class         fg
                 A          Z
                 B          Z
                 C          Z
                 D          Y
                 E          Y
                 F          X",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

class_df  <- read.table(text = 
"id    A    B    C    D    E    F
1 0.20 0.30 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.00 
2 0.05 0.10 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.40
3 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.30",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Want to say thank you because adding all these answers to a small example library so I can be more flexible in future.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option, along with the already contributed working solutions,
would be to use [quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html)
with the `rlang` package to build expressions to calculate the sums in each
group.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First, define a helper function for doing an elementwise sum of vectors:

```
psum <- function(...) reduce(list(...), `+`)
```

Extracting the groupings into a list from `class_fg` we can then construct
a list of expressions to calculate the sum in each group:

```
sum_exprs <- with(class_fg, split(class, fg)) %>% 
  map(~ rlang::expr(psum(!!!rlang::syms(.x))))

sum_exprs
#> $X
#> psum(F)
#> 
#> $Y
#> psum(D, E)
#> 
#> $Z
#> psum(A, B, C)
```

With the list of expressions ready, we can just ["bang-bang-bang" (`!!!`)](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#with-rlang-1) them into the data with `mutate`:

```
class_df %>%
  mutate(!!!sum_exprs)
#>   id    A   B    C    D    E   F   X   Y   Z
#> 1  1 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6
#> 2  2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2
#> 3  3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3
```

(I used the code provided by @MKR in his answer to create the data).

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Want to say thank you because adding all these answers to a small example library so I can be more flexible in future.

Answer (score 1):

My usual approach is to stick to `base` R as long as the data sets don't get too large. In your case, a `base` R solution would be:

```
class_df=as.data.frame(
  c(class_df,
    lapply(split(class_fg,class_fg$fg),
           function(x) rowSums(class_df[,x$class,drop=FALSE]))))
class_df
#  id    A   B    C    D    E   F   X   Y   Z
#1  1 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6
#2  2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2
#3  3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3
```

If the data sets get too large, I use `data.table`. A `data.table` solution for your problem:

```
library(data.table)

class_dt=data.table(class_df)
grps=split(class_fg,class_fg$fg)

for (g in grps) class_dt[,c(g$fg[1]):=rowSums(.SD),.SDcols=g$class,]
class_dt
#   id    A   B    C    D    E   F   X   Y   Z
#1:  1 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6
#2:  2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2
#3:  3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `tidyverse` solution using `rowSums` on column subsets :

```r
library(tidyverse)
class_fg %>%
  group_by(fg) %>% 
  summarize(list(rowSums(class_df[class]))) %>%
  spread(1,2) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  bind_cols(class_df, .)

#>   id    A   B    C    D    E   F   X   Y   Z
#> 1  1 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6
#> 2  2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2
#> 3  3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3
```

Or for the glory of code golf :

```
x <- with(class_fg, tapply(class, fg, reformulate))
mutate(class_df, !!!map(x, ~as.list(.)[[2]]))
#>   id    A   B    C    D    E   F   X   Y   Z
#> 1  1 0.20 0.3 0.10 0.15 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6
#> 2  2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.30 0.10 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2
#> 3  3 0.10 0.1 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3
```