# Apply a function to a subset of many columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

How do I apply a function to many columns of grouped rows? For example;

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
  ~Date,      ~Seq1, ~Component, ~Seq2,  ~X1,  ~X2,   ~X3,   
  "01/01/18", 1,     "Smooth",   NA,     3.98,  2.75,  1.82, 
  "01/01/18", 2,     "Smooth",   NA,     1.02,  0.02, -0.04, 
  "01/01/18", 3,     "Smooth",   NA,     3.48,  3.06,  1.25, 
  "01/01/18", 3,     "Bounce",   1,      2.01, -0.43, -0.52, 
  "01/01/18", 3,     "Bounce",   2,      1.94,  1.53,  1.92) %>%
mutate_at(vars(Date, Seq1, Component, Seq2), funs(factor))
```

Each column of *X* values (many more columns, truncated here for clarity) is grouped into *Date*, *Seq1*, *Component*, and *Seq2*. While *Component* "Smooth" and *Seq1* "NA" are constant, within *Component* "Bounce" level there are multiple *Seq2* levels e.g. "1", "2", etc.

How do I sum each *X* column, always the constant "NA" with each level of *Seq2*?

The desired results is:

```r
expected <- tribble(
~Date,      ~Seq1, ~Component, ~Seq2,  ~X1,  ~X2,   ~X3,   
"01/01/18", 1,     "Smooth",   NA,     3.98,  2.75,  1.82, 
"01/01/18", 2,     "Smooth",   NA,     1.02,  0.02, -0.04, 
"01/01/18", 3,     "Smooth",   NA,     3.48,  3.06,  1.25, 
"01/01/18", 3,     "Bounce",   1,      5.49,  3.49,  1.77, 
"01/01/18", 3,     "Bounce",   2,      5.42,  4.59,  3.17)
```

The following example only adds each Seq1 level.

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(Date, Seq1) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("X")), funs(sum(.)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#> # Groups:   Date, Seq1 [3]
#>   Date     Seq1  Component  Seq2    X1    X2    X3
#>   <fct>    <fct> <fct>     <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 01/01/18 1     Smooth    <NA>   3.98  2.75  1.82
#> 2 01/01/18 2     Smooth    <NA>   1.02  0.02 -0.04
#> 3 01/01/18 3     Smooth    <NA>   7.43  4.16  2.65
#> 4 01/01/18 3     Bounce    1      7.43  4.16  2.65
#> 5 01/01/18 3     Bounce    2      7.43  4.16  2.65
```

I am certain there is solution within the `purrr` or `apply` function family, however, I have been unsuccessful (for days) in solving this example. The actual data has about 180 *X* columns, with hundreds of *Date* and *Seq1* combinations, and multiple *Seq2* levels.

A similar example could be [Summing Multiple Groups of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460273/summing-multiple-groups-of-columns), [How to apply a function to a subset of columns in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519976/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-subset-of-columns-in-r), or even perhaps https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows.

<sup>Created on 2018-10-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Can you provide your expected output from this data? I do not understand what "How do I sum each X column, always the constant "NA" with each level of Seq2?" means. Why is your attempt not correct?

Comment: Perhaps `data %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(.[grep("^X\\d+", names(.))]))`

Comment: My attempt is incorrect because it sums each column only at the Seq1 level e.g. X1 row 3-5 are the same, rather than in the desired results.

Comment: It is still unclear to me how do you get to `5.49,  3.49,  1.77` and `5.42,  4.59,  3.17`

Comment: @deann it is through [row, column]: `[3, X1] + [4, X1], [3, X2] + [4, X2], [3, X3] + [4, X3]` and `[3, X1] + [5, X1], [3, X2] + [5, X2], [3, X3] + [5, X3]`. Note how, for each X column, Component == "smooth" is always added to each Component == "Bounce". That is, when there is a Bounce component (per sequence in Seq2) add the Smooth component. Later, the X1, X2, X3, etc. will be used to plot a series of lines.

Comment: Really tough to understand the meaning of the question, as @CalumYou observes.

Comment: Is there always only one `Smooth` for each `Seq1`, but many potential `Bounce`?

Comment: @CalumYou correct; there can be 0-4 potential `Bounce` components for each `Seq1`. Up to 4 is the maximum in this data set, however there could be more in other data sets so I don't think that should be hard-coded. 
I apologise it is not easier to understand… what more can I explain? I am unsure of how to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. This problem is not really a `purrr` task, because there is nothing really that you want to map a single function to. Instead, what I understand the problem to be is that you want to match each `X` value in a `Bounce` row with the corresponding `Smooth` row `X` values of the same `Date` and `Seq1` (and there is only one such row). This means that it is really a merging or joining problem, and then the approach is to set up the join so that you can match the right values and do the sum. So I go as follows:

1. Split the data into the `Smooth` rows and the `Bounce` rows and `gather` so that all the `X` values are in one column
2. Join the `smooths` onto the `bounces` with a `left_join`, so each original `Bounce` row now has its corresponding `Smooth`.
3. `mutate` the sum into a new column and select/rename the columns to be as in the original
4. `bind_rows` to join the newly summed `bounces` and `spread` to return to the original layout.

This should be robust to any number of `Date`, `Seq1`, `Seq2` and `X` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
  ~Date,      ~Seq1, ~Component, ~Seq2,  ~X1,  ~X2,   ~X3,   
  "01/01/18", 1,     "Smooth",   NA,     3.98,  2.75,  1.82, 
  "01/01/18", 2,     "Smooth",   NA,     1.02,  0.02, -0.04, 
  "01/01/18", 3,     "Smooth",   NA,     3.48,  3.06,  1.25, 
  "01/01/18", 3,     "Bounce",   1,      2.01, -0.43, -0.52, 
  "01/01/18", 3,     "Bounce",   2,      1.94,  1.53,  1.92)

smooths <- data %>%
  filter(Component == "Smooth") %>%
  gather(X, val, starts_with("X"))

bounces <- data %>%
  filter(Component == "Bounce") %>%
  gather(X, val, starts_with("X")) %>%
  left_join(smooths, by = c("Date", "Seq1", "X")) %>%
  mutate(val = val.x + val.y) %>%
  select(Date, Seq1, Component = Component.x, Seq2 = Seq2.x, X, val)

bounces %>%
  bind_rows(smooths) %>%
  spread(X, val)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   Date      Seq1 Component  Seq2    X1    X2    X3
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 01/01/18     1 Smooth       NA  3.98  2.75  1.82
#> 2 01/01/18     2 Smooth       NA  1.02  0.02 -0.04
#> 3 01/01/18     3 Bounce        1  5.49  2.63  0.73
#> 4 01/01/18     3 Bounce        2  5.42  4.59  3.17
#> 5 01/01/18     3 Smooth       NA  3.48  3.06  1.25
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Great! That works as expected. 
Although, the last `spread` doesn't seem to respect the key order, so when there is many X columns then the newly spread column order becomes X1, X10, X11, etc. rather than X1, X2, X3... X10, X11.

Comment: This X sequence mis-arrangement was solved through with `select(Date, Seq1, Component, Seq2, paste("X", seq(1, ncol(select(., starts_with("X"))), 1), sep=""))`